# cannot crop image into a real circle

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use code following to try to crop a circle instead of oval, but in vain.
code, https://jsfiddle.net/Debra321/432574uc/98/

code snippet,

```
.circle{
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
position: relative;
border: 2px solid white;
-webkit-border-radius: 70px;
-moz-border-radius: 70px;
border-radius: 70px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Effect I need: crop the background image into a real circle.

What I've tried: with code bellow I could crop a circle image properly, but because I need the visible border, I give up this solution.

```
.circle{
position:absolute;
width:80px;
height:80px;
top:-2%;
background:#0cc;
-webkit-clip-path:circle(40% at center);
border-width:3px;
border-color:white;
}
```

wrong effect(left)  &   right effect(right)

[image]

part of code structure is from [Trying to circular crop image with HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831225/trying-to-circular-crop-image-with-html-and-css).

cropped image is the background of an item in the flexbox.
Any feedback is appreciated; thank you.

My html code,

```
<div id="phoneContent">
   <div class="colContainer">
       <div class="circle"> 
       </div>
            <h3>
             ONE
            </h3>
       <div>
           <h1>
           TWO
           </h1>
       </div>
       <div>
           <h1>
           THREE
           </h1>
       </div>
       <div>
           <h1>
           FOUR
           </h1>
       </div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

and css,

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #fcfca4;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #F3E9D2, #EC9192);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position:relative;
}
#phoneContent{
    position: absolute;
    top:17.7%;
    left:50px;
    width:253px;
    height:455px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto; 
    overflow: auto;   

}
#phoneContent .colContainer{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   display: flex;
   top:15%;
   flex-direction: column;
   position: absolute;
}
.colContainer >  div{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.circle{
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
position: relative;
border: 2px solid white;
-webkit-border-radius: 70px;
-moz-border-radius: 70px;
border-radius: 70px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.colContainer >  div:nth-child(1) {
background:url("http://gdurl.com/hZIP") no-repeat -120px,0;
background-size:cover;
filter: brightness(50%);
position:relative;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you're trying to set a height to flexbox, that's not what they're made for. I've done a quick fix to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/432574uc/101/

(commented this code in fiddle)

```
.colContainer >  div{/*
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I really need flex:1 because I need 4 elements to full evenly the parent div. Is it possible to un-comment flex:1 but also keep the circle at the same time?